# Simple Adapter some does not respond to click

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display two line `ListView` in `Alert Dialog`. I am creating new view which has `ListView` and set it to use Simple `Adapter`.  I populate Simple adapter with a `hashmap` of `string` which i get through `JSONArray`.When i display it i want to catch on click event as show in code, but list items do not respond to click. However if i populate just a regular `string` with text to the `ListView`, the item gets clicked. Code below:

```
View view = Testas.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.commands_listview, null);
                    trackersHash = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    trackersAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(Testas.this, trackersHash, R.layout.commands_listview_layout, new String[] {"line1","line2"}, new int[] {R.id.command, R.id.explanation});
                    ListView trackersListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
                    trackersListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    trackersListView.setClickable(true);
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap;else if (jsonArray.length() > 10)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                            {//GETS displayed, but does not respond when i Click on it
                                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                hashMap.put("line1", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("licence").trim());
                                hashMap.put("line2", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("hwid").trim());
                                trackersHash.add(hashMap);
                            }

                            hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();//Gets displayed and RESPONDS to Click
                            hashMap.put("line1", "Note: Query has a result of more than 10 items.");
                            hashMap.put("line2", "Please clarify car/tracker data to receive more accurate results");
                            trackersHash.add(hashMap);
                        }

                        trackersListView.setAdapter(trackersAdapter);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Testas.this);
                        builder.setView(view);
                        trackersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    carReg.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("licence").trim());
                                    carBrand.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("brand").trim());
                                    carComp.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("company").trim());
                                    carID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("hwid");
                                }

                                catch (JSONException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                Pagrindinis.socketIntent = new Intent(Testas.this, SocketService.class);
                                Pagrindinis.socketIntent.putExtra("type", 0);
                                Pagrindinis.socketIntent.putExtra("carId", carID);
                                startService(Pagrindinis.socketIntent);

                                Toast.makeText(Testas.this, "Parsing Data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setTitle("Select Tracker:");
                        builder.show();
```

If i put simple text in `string` inside for loop parse everything works fine so i think it is something wrong with parsing `string` from `JSONArray`, but they get displayed as `string`s as well so i dont know whats wrong then. Any Ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? If yes post stacktrace.

Comment: No errors at all, JSONException is not thrown as well... Everything works as expected except the stuff explained above...

Comment: Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: Sorry :) No errors thrown, Everything works as expected except that the parsed strings from jsonArray does not respond to click